# How do I find all the keys common in 2 maps?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector

I have 3 maps:

```
map<string, vector<int> > map1
map<string, vector<int> > map2
map<string, vector<int> > map3
```

I need to create a third map with all the strings existing in both map1 and map2 with their corresponding vectors. Thing is, even if the strings are same, their vectors can be different and i have to append all the vectors from both the common strings into 1 vector.
This is what I'm trying but I'm kind of lost:

```
for(map<string, vector<int> >::iterator it1=map1.begin(); it1 != map1.end(); it1++)
{
    string name = (*it1).first;
    for(map<string, vector<int> >::iterator it2=map2.begin(); it2 != map2.end(); it2++)
    {
        string name2 = (*it2).first;
        if (name == name2)
        {
            map3[name2] = (*it2).second;

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Are you doing a set intersection of the keys (the result is only those keys that are present in both), or a set union (the result will have a key if it appears in map1 or map2 or both).

Comment: @sumrania: Union would be all the keys in A AND all the keys in B, not all the keys that are only in both sets. Dave S is correct.

Comment: @ChrisDoggett I need to find all the keys in A and all the keys in B but the common keys should appear only once and not twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the maps are ordered you can do this in linear time. This is one possible way to do the task:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> vec_t;
typedef std::map<std::string, vec_t> map_t;
typedef map_t::const_iterator iter_t;

int main()
{
    map_t map1, map2, map3;

    iter_t it1 = map1.begin();
    iter_t it2 = map2.begin();

    while (it1 != map1.end() && it2 != map2.end()) {
        if (it1->first < it2->first) {
            ++it1;
        } else if (it2->first < it1->first) {
            ++it2;
        } else { // equal keys
            vec_t temp(it1->second);
            temp.insert(temp.end(), it2->second.begin(), it2->second.end());
            map3[it1->first].swap(temp); // swap contents to new map entry
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes the map key ordering is the default `less<Key>`.

Comment: Aren't it1->first and it2->first strings? How are you using an if condition which sets one string less than the other?

Comment: @sumrania: Yes, the keys are strings. Since the contents of the maps are sorted by their keys I'm just using __string comparison__ to test which string is less than the other. The keys aren't being altered, just compared. (`std::string` defines an `operator<` that performs _less-than_ comparison).

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
#include <algorithm>  // for std::copy
#include <iterator>   // for std::back_inserter
#include <map>
...

for(auto it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); ++it)
{
   auto fit = map2.find(it->first);
   if(fit != map2.end()
   {
      map3[it->first] = it->second;
      std::copy(fit->second.begin(), fit->second.end(), std::back_inserter(map3[it->first]));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is

```
map3 = map1;
typedef map<string, vector<int> > map_type;

for(map_type::iterator itr = map2.begin(); itr != map2.end(); ++itr)
{
    vector<int>& ref = map3[itr->first];
    ref.insert(ref.end(), itr->second.begin(), itr->second.end());
}
```

This first copies all entries from the first map into the destination.  It then, for each entry in the map, looks up the corresponding entry in the output map.  If it didn't already exist, it creates a new vector (via `map::operator[]`), otherwise, it returns the reference to the existing on.  The vector in the second map is then appended to the vector already in the result.

The downside is you're searching the resulting map over and over again in the destination map, which seems to be a bit excessive. Since both maps are sorted, it should be able to do it in linear time, instead of N-log-N time.