# How could I obtain the common keys of two std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, std

Suppose there are two c++ `std::map`s:

```
std::map<string, int> m1{{"n1", 1}, {"n2", 2}, {"n3", 3}};
std::map<string, int> m2{{"n2", 3}, {"n4", 2}, {"n1", 9}};
```

I would like to obtain a `std::set` that contains the common keys of the two maps.

```
std::set<string> common = ...;
```

I hope I can do it elegantly, so I better avoid using loops and it would be better if I can find some method in the `std` namespace or from `<algorithm>`, how could I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find all the keys common in 2 maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844453/how-do-i-find-all-the-keys-common-in-2-maps)

Comment: You could, in theory, combine e.g. a `std::transform` and a `std::erase_if` if you don't want to use loops directly. But the more efficient way would be using the accepted answer of the possible duplicate.

Comment: How about using [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection)?

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution with a [`std::set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection):

```
template<class It>
class Key_iterator {
public:
    Key_iterator(It it) : it_(it) {}

    Key_iterator& operator++() {
        ++it_;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const Key_iterator& other) const {
        return it_ == other.it_;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Key_iterator& other) const {
        return it_ != other.it_;
    }

    auto operator*() const {
        return it_->first;
    }    

private:
    It it_;
};

std::map<std::string, int> m1{{"n1", 1}, {"n2", 2}, {"n3", 3}};
std::map<std::string, int> m2{{"n2", 3}, {"n4", 2}, {"n1", 9}};

std::vector<std::string> s;
std::set_intersection(Key_iterator(m1.begin()), Key_iterator(m1.end()),
        Key_iterator(m2.begin()), Key_iterator(m2.end()), std::back_inserter(s));

// s = {"n1", "n2"}
```

`std::set_intersection` requires both ranges to be sorted, and `std::map` keeps its keys in the sorted order. So they fit nicely.

---

If Boost is available, there is no need to code `Key_iterator` adapter. With [`boost::transform_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/transform.html) this code can be simplified to:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m1{{"n1", 1}, {"n2", 2}, {"n3", 3}};
std::map<std::string, int> m2{{"n2", 3}, {"n4", 2}, {"n1", 9}};

auto key_iterator = [](auto it) {
    return boost::transform_iterator(it, [](auto& p) { return p.first; });
};

std::vector<std::string> s;
std::set_intersection(key_iterator(m1.begin()), key_iterator(m1.end()),
    key_iterator(m2.begin()), key_iterator(m2.end()), std::back_inserter(s));
```

Comment: really love that Key_iterator solution. Doing a lot of map-alg right now, this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

To find the common keys, you need to filter the items of `m1` whose key isn't in `m2`, then extract the key. Sadly, there's not a `transform_if` or any kind of combined filter/map operation in `<algorithm>`, so if you're using pure algorithms it's a two-step operation:

```cpp
std::map<string, int> common_m;
std::copy_if(
    m1.begin(), m1.end(), 
    std::inserter(common_m, common_m.end()), 
    [&m2](auto&& kv) { return m2.find(kv.first) != m2.end(); });

std::set<string> common_keys;
std::transform(
    common_m.begin(), common_m.end(), 
    std::inserter(common_keys, common_keys.end()), 
    [](auto&& kv) { return kv.first; });
```

Demo - https://godbolt.org/z/6982Pm

Composing steps in `<algorithm>` is awkward because there are no lazy operations, each one has to be materialized in a new container.

This is what the [ranges-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library, which has been incorporated into the C++20 standard as the [Ranges TS](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), enables. It allows for ML-style lazy operations that can be composed to make this a one-liner:

```cpp
std::set<string> common_keys = m1
    | views::remove_if([&m2](auto&& kv) { return m2.find(kv.first) == m2.end(); })
    | views::transform([](auto&& kv) { return kv.first; })
    | to<std::set>;
```

Demo - https://godbolt.org/z/CKUFFz